# 7Zip CLI multipart extraction issue. Proceeding part overwrites existing

Tags: command-line, 7-zip, extract, rar

I am looking for a way to use 7zip to decompress multipart achives via CLI.

So far I have the below which extracts as expected but instead of joining the parts, overwrites the existing contents with the next parts extracted content.

```
for /R "L:\-\BBDsdr" %%I in ("*.zip" "*.7z" "*.rar") do ("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -pThePassword -y -o"F:\BBDsdr" "%%~fI" -bsp2)
```

e.g:

```
BBDsdr.part1.rar (5GB)
BBDsdr.part2.rar (5GB)
BBDsdr.part3.rar (5GB)  
BBDsdr.part4.rar (350MB)
```

I am not sure if you will be able to replicate the result but what I get after the command finishes is a 350MB ISO instead of 15GB+.

I tried adding "*.part1.rar" to the filter but this only works if I exclude the ".rar" part, which unfortunately I cannot remove due to alot of the other archives not been multipart.

Manual extration via the GUI works without issue, but there are over 3000 folders I have to go through so I am trying to automate this whole process.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try renaming the files, as in; part1.rar, part2.r01, part3.r02, part4.r03 - then use as if there was only a part1.rar

Comment: @Hannu, looked promising but I am getting "Missing volume : ??????.part2.rar" after changing the extensions

Comment: The base name of all files must be the same; i.e. remove the numbers. part.rar, part.r01, ... forgot about that. Sorry ;-)

Comment: @Hannu, working with r00 onwards. The unfortunate thing lies in the 3000 folders I would have to rename the files in. Will reseach a quick way of doing this, but also hoping that there is a solution or tweak for the "FOR" command above. Either way, your solution at least takes care of the overwriting issue, so thank you very much.

Comment: Please can a Mod, mark this as resolved. I found a way of renaming all files in the 3000 folders using the forfiles command (e.g. forfiles /S /M *.part2 /C "cmd /c rename @ file @ fname.r00"). Thank you again @Hannu, you solution did the trick afterall

Comment: @David the way to mark the question as resolved is for what you've found to be posted as an answer. It may help others in the future. From the comments, you may wish to let Hannu post the answer so that you can credit Hannu by upvoting and ticking it as your accepted answer. Or if it's mostly your own answer, just post it yourself and accept it.

Comment: @Reg Edit, 100 percent. If Hannu posts his solution, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Well, done it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RAR](https://www.win-rar.com) The archiver has several ways of naming files when they form a "multivolume archive". (Many files, a single archive).

```
BBDsdr.part1.rar (5GB)
BBDsdr.part2.rar (5GB)
BBDsdr.part3.rar (5GB)  
BBDsdr.part4.rar (350MB)
```

is one way

Renaming the files as

```
BBDsdr.part.rar (5GB)
BBDsdr.part.r00 (5GB)
BBDsdr.part.r01 (5GB)  
BBDsdr.part.r02 (350MB)
```

... should make it also work.

There might be more ways that I'm not remembering at time of writing.

Which one of the file naming styles that work with other versions of RAR, or even other archivers (7zip, WinZip, ...) might differ quite a bit.

Edit:
**Basics with multi volume archives: You open the FIRST file only, the archive utilty recognizes that it is a multivolume and uses the other files.**

*HTH*

Comment: what you remembered is exactly what did the trick. Thanks again